# How to run 'tox' command for 'py.test' for python module?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, tox

Using python 3.6 (on a Mac Mojave; no virtualenv involved) I have the following setup: A folder containing the two folders

```
mymodule1
tests
```

The folder `mymodule1` contains two files, an empty file `__init__.py` and a file `myfunctions.py`:

```
def func1(x):
    return 2*x
```

and the folder `test` contains one file `test_1.py`:

```
from mymodule1 import myfunctions

def test1():
    assert myfunctions.func1(21) == 42
```

Since I want to run a `py.test` within a tox environment, I also have the following two files in the main folder:

First the `tox.ini` file (according to numerous examples):

```
[base]
name = mymodule1

[tox]
envlist =
    py36

[testenv]
deps =
    pytest

commands = pytest
```

which has the command `pytest` ***and not*** `python -m pytest`!!
Then the `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="mymodule1",
    author="me",
    description="Short description",
    long_description="long description",
)
```

Running the command

```
pytest
```

on the command line gives the following error:

```
======================================================================================== test session starts ========================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.9, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /Users/adietz/mymodule
plugins: cov-2.10.0
collected 0 items / 1 error                                                                                                                                                                         

============================================================================================== ERRORS ===============================================================================================
_________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_1.py __________________________________________________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/adietz/mymodule/tests/test_1.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
tests/test_1.py:2: in <module>
    from mymodule1 import myfunctions
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mymodule1'
====================================================================================== short test summary info ======================================================================================
ERROR tests/test_1.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========================================================================================= 1 error in 0.13s ==========================================================================================
```

and running `tox -e py36` gives the following output:

```
GLOB sdist-make: /Users/adietz/mymodule/setup.py
py36 create: /Users/adietz/mymodule/.tox/py36
py36 installdeps: pytest
py36 inst: /Users/adietz/mymodule/.tox/.tmp/package/1/mymodule1-0.0.0.zip
py36 installed: attrs==19.3.0,importlib-metadata==1.7.0,more-itertools==8.4.0,mymodule1 @ file:///Users/adietz/mymodule/.tox/.tmp/package/1/mymodule1-0.0.0.zip,packaging==20.4,pluggy==0.13.1,py==1.9.0,pyparsing==2.4.7,pytest==5.4.3,six==1.15.0,wcwidth==0.2.5,zipp==3.1.0
py36 run-test-pre: PYTHONHASHSEED='1211015963'
py36 run-test: commands[0] | pytest
======================================================================================== test session starts ========================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.9, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
cachedir: .tox/py36/.pytest_cache
rootdir: /Users/adietz/mymodule
collected 0 items / 1 error                                                                                                                                                                         

============================================================================================== ERRORS ===============================================================================================
_________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_1.py __________________________________________________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/adietz/mymodule/tests/test_1.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
tests/test_1.py:2: in <module>
    from mymodule1 import myfunctions
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mymodule1'
====================================================================================== short test summary info ======================================================================================
ERROR tests/test_1.py
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========================================================================================= 1 error in 0.12s ==========================================================================================
ERROR: InvocationError for command /Users/adietz/mymodule/.tox/py36/bin/pytest (exited with code 2)
______________________________________________________________________________________________ summary ______________________________________________________________________________________________
ERROR:   py36: commands failed
```

What am I missing? **How is it possible that other people can use a `tox.ini` file invoking `pytest`/`py.test` directly?**

To be very clear: I am not looking for a workaround. I am looking for an explanation, so that I can use a `tox.ini` file invoking `pytest`/`py.test` directly. I want to know why it is not working for me, when it is working for thousand of other packages. What are they doing differenty?

**Additional information:**

```
$ which python
/Users/adietz/.pyenv/shims/python
$ which pytest
/Users/adietz/.pyenv/shims/pytest
```

Comment: Note that `py.test` is long deprecated in favour of `pytest`. Apart from that, you need to have your root path in the Python path - there are different possibilities to achieve this, using `python -m pytest` is one of them, adding the path explicitely in the code (for example in `__init__.py`) is another.

Comment: Doing the import in `__init__.py` inside `mymodule1`: `from mymodule1 import myfunctions` gives the same error.

Comment: What I meant is something like `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))` in `__init__.py`.

Comment: In a working example of a different repo this is not done. So I also do not do it. There must be something else magically going on

Answer (score 1):

The solution to all the problem might be in the `setup.py`! Just change it to the following code:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="mymodule1",
    author="me",
    description="Short description",
    long_description="long description",
    packages=find_packages()
)
```

which then seems to 'find all the packages' and it works.

Maybe you might find that tiny, but extremely important aspect when you read ***all*** of the documentation for

- python
- pytest
- tox
- setup.py